# Why isn't Matplotlib+Basemap showing islands?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I've been working with matplotlib and basemap to show some information about New York City. Up until now, I've been following [this guide](http://www.datadependence.com/2016/06/creating-map-visualisations-in-python/), but I've hit an issue. I'm trying to show manhattan island within my visualization, but I can't figure out why basemap isn't showing it as an island.

Here's the visualization that basemap is giving me:

[image]

Here's a screenshot of the bounding box I'm using:

[image]

And here's the code that is generating the image:

```
wl = -74.04006
sl = 40.683092
el = -73.834067
nl = 40.88378

m = Basemap(resolution='f', # c, l, i, h, f or None
            projection='merc',
            area_thresh=50,
            lat_0=(wl + sl)/2, lon_0=(el + nl)/2,
            llcrnrlon= wl, llcrnrlat= sl, urcrnrlon= el, urcrnrlat= nl)

m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#46bcec')
m.fillcontinents(color='#f2f2f2',lake_color='#46bcec')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawrivers()
```

I thought that it might consider the water in between a river, but `m.drawrivers()` didn't appear to fix it. Any help is obviously extremely appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

One approach to get a better quality base map for your plots is building one from web map tiles at an appropriate zoom level. Here I demonstrate how to get them from `openstreetmap` web map servers. In this case, I use zoom level 10, and get 2 map tiles to combined as single image array. One of the drawbacks, the extent of the combined image is always larger than the values we asked for. Here is the working code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
import urllib2
import StringIO
from PIL import Image

# === Begin block1 ===
# Credit: BerndGit, answered Feb 15 '15 at 19:47. And ...
# Source: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames

def deg2num(lat_deg, lon_deg, zoom):
    '''Lon./lat. to tile numbers'''
    lat_rad = math.radians(lat_deg)
    n = 2.0 ** zoom
    xtile = int((lon_deg + 180.0) / 360.0 * n)
    ytile = int((1.0 - math.log(math.tan(lat_rad) + (1 / math.cos(lat_rad))) / math.pi) / 2.0 * n)
    return (xtile, ytile)

def num2deg(xtile, ytile, zoom):
    '''Tile numbers to lon./lat.'''
    n = 2.0 ** zoom
    lon_deg = xtile / n * 360.0 - 180.0
    lat_rad = math.atan(math.sinh(math.pi * (1 - 2 * ytile / n)))
    lat_deg = math.degrees(lat_rad)
    return (lat_deg, lon_deg)   # NW-corner of the tile. 

def getImageCluster(lat_deg, lon_deg, delta_lat, delta_long, zoom):
    # access map tiles from internet
    # no access/key or password is needed
    smurl = r"http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{0}/{1}/{2}.png"
    # useful snippet: smurl.format(zoom, xtile, ytile) -> complete URL
    # x increases L-R; y Top-Bottom
    xmin, ymax =deg2num(lat_deg, lon_deg, zoom)  # get tile numbers (x,y)
    xmax, ymin =deg2num(lat_deg+delta_lat, lon_deg+delta_long, zoom)

    # PIL is used to build new image from tiles
    Cluster = Image.new('RGB',((xmax-xmin+1)*256-1,(ymax-ymin+1)*256-1) ) 
    for xtile in range(xmin, xmax+1):
        for ytile in range(ymin,  ymax+1):
            try:
                imgurl = smurl.format(zoom, xtile, ytile)
                print("Opening: " + imgurl)
                imgstr = urllib2.urlopen(imgurl).read()
                # TODO: study, what these do?
                tile = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(imgstr))
                Cluster.paste(tile, box=((xtile-xmin)*256 ,  (ytile-ymin)*255))
            except: 
                print("Couldn't download image")
                tile = None
    return Cluster
# ===End Block1===

# Credit to myself
def getextents(latmin_deg, lonmin_deg, delta_lat, delta_long, zoom):
    '''Return LL and UR, each with (long,lat) of real extent of combined tiles.
       latmin_deg: bottom lat of extent
       lonmin_deg: left long of extent
       delta_lat: extent of lat
       delta_long: extent of long, all in degrees
    '''
    # Tile numbers(x,y): x increases L-R; y Top-Bottom
    xtile_LL, ytile_LL = deg2num(latmin_deg, lonmin_deg, zoom)  #get tile numbers as specified by (x, y)
    xtile_UR, ytile_UR = deg2num(latmin_deg + delta_lat, lonmin_deg + delta_long, zoom)
    # from tile numbers, we get NW corners
    lat_NW_LL, lon_NW_LL = num2deg(xtile_LL, ytile_LL, zoom)
    lat_NW_LLL, lon_NW_LLL = num2deg(xtile_LL, ytile_LL+1, zoom) # next down below

    lat_NW_UR, lon_NW_UR = num2deg(xtile_UR, ytile_UR, zoom)
    lat_NW_URR, lon_NW_URR = num2deg(xtile_UR+1, ytile_UR, zoom) # next to the right
    # get extents
    minLat = lat_NW_LLL
    minLon = lon_NW_LL
    maxLat = lat_NW_UR
    maxLon = lon_NW_URR
    return (minLon, maxLon, minLat, maxLat)  # (left, right, bottom, top) in degrees

# OP's values of extents for target area to plot
# some changes here (with larger zoom level) may lead to better final plot
wl = -74.04006
sl = 40.683092
el = -73.834067
nl = 40.88378

lat_deg = sl
lon_deg = wl
d_lat = nl - sl
d_long = el - wl
zoom = 10   # zoom level

# Acquire images. The combined images will be slightly larger that the extents
timg = getImageCluster(lat_deg, lon_deg, d_lat, d_long, zoom)

# This computes real extents of the combined tile images, and get (left, right, bottom, top)
latmin_deg, lonmin_deg, delta_lat, delta_long = sl, wl, nl-sl, el-wl
(left, right, bottom, top) = getextents(latmin_deg, lonmin_deg, delta_lat, delta_long, zoom)   #units: degrees

# Set Basemap with proper parameters
m = Basemap(resolution='h',  # h is nice
            projection='merc',
            area_thresh=50,
            lat_0=(bottom + top)/2, lon_0=(left + right)/2,
            llcrnrlon=left, llcrnrlat=bottom, urcrnrlon=right, urcrnrlat=top)

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(10, 12)
m.imshow(np.asarray(timg), extent=[left, right, bottom, top], origin='upper' )
m.drawcoastlines(color='gray', linewidth=3.0)  # intentionally thick line
#m.fillcontinents(color='#f2f2f2', lake_color='#46bcec', alpha=0.6)
plt.show()
```

Hope it helps. The resulting plot:

[image]

**Edit**

To crop the image in order to get the exact area to plot is not difficult. The `PIL` module can handle that. Numpy's array slicing also works.